# WooCommerce products loop data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to be able to grab all the content that the shortcode [best_selling_products limit="4"] does but within a WP_Query loop. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far;

```
<?php   
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="container" id="best_sellers">
        <div class="row">
        <?php while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know I can grab the title, price, link, thumbnail etc. But what I dont know how to grab is the add to cart button. Is it possible to get this within my loop or will I have to create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get product object in while loop:

```
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
```

Then you can get add to cart url and text by:

```
$product->add_to_cart_url()
$product->add_to_cart_text()
```

Comment: Both yours and Elvins methods work. But I prefer this method as it allows me more control of the layout. thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

```
<?php while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <?php 
     do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
     wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
     ?>
     </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

For more details about how WooCommerce loop content is rendered, you can check woocommerce template files which are in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates directory.